# Reusing Android bitmaps for loading many images

Tags: android, bitmap, memory-management

My app needs to display long animation with separate full-screen size images per frame. 
AnimationDrawable can not be used, as I can not load all images in memory (about 300 images will be around 100 Mb).

So what I'm trying to do is to load image every frame without keeping it in memory.
But in order to keep memory usage low, I'm trying to avoid any allocations in my thread loop.

I found that Android SDK v3 has interesting feature in BitmapFactory.Options.inBitmap which tries to decode stream into specified bitmap (if it can).

My question is: Is it possible to reproduce the same feature (BitmapFactory.Options.inBitmap) for SDK v2?

Comment: are you sure you want to develop for android 1.1? I really don't think anyone has 1.1 on their phones anymore.

Comment: Not for 1.1, but at least for 2

Comment: you mean android version 2.0? SDK API level 2 is 1.1

Comment: Regarding the Android Version and SKD level, look [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) to see the correspondance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little misinformed.  SDK level 2 corresponds to Android 1.1, and I believe you want to develop for Android 2.0 and above, which is SDK level 5. You should have no problems using that feature which came from SDK level 3.

In general, "Updates to the framework API are designed so that the new API remains compatible with earlier versions of the API."

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html

Edit: A feature that was introduced at SDK level 11 (Android 3.0) is not available for phones below 3.0.

Comment: Yeah, I meant Android v2.0. But the feature inBitmap appeared in SDK level 11 - http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/11/changes/android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options.html

Comment: In that case, no, you can't use it it with Android 2.0 (SDK level 8) because that field isn't on those phones.  Android 2.0 phones have no idea what features are on Android 3.0 phones.

Answer (score 0):

first, you are not talking about the SDK, but about the android version as it is shown to end users (honeycomb ,which is 3.x vs gingerbread and below which is 2.x ).

the real thing to look at is the API number . the feature you are talking about has started from API11 (honeycomb) , so you can't use it on older devices, unless you get android's code and do the same for your app.

here's a tutorial of how to use this cool feature:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsQet4nBVi8